# Maxima in single-slit diffraction

Tags: optics, waves, diffraction

The width of a **minimum** in single-slit diffraction is related to

$\ d \sin \theta=n \lambda$

where $\sin\theta = \frac{y}{L}$ by small angle approximation.

However, Wikipedia says that there is no such formula for the width of an n-th **maximum** in single-slit diffraction. Why is that so?

Comment: What is the meaning of "d" in this formula?

Comment: Width of the slit.

Comment: Then how is this formula giving the width of the minimum? Where is the width in it?

Comment: I should have written "angular position". To be honest, I was somewhat confused about the topic in November. In the meantime, I studied it more thoroughly in the context of the intensity profile of the pattern. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in single slit diffraction is that there is an exception when considering the maxima. The central maximum is actually twice as wide as the other maxima. If you take this exception into account however the same formula that is valid for the minima is also valid for the maxima.

All minima have a width

$\Delta y = \lambda L /d$

The same applies to the maxima except for the centre which has a width of

$\Delta y = 2 \lambda L /d$