# Single slit diffraction angle between maxima

Tags: waves, interference, diffraction

Lets say we have a certain wavelength $\lambda$ and a known slit width $d$, how can I calculate (approximately) the angle $\theta$ between the ***central maxima*** and the next **maxima**?

I know that $d \sin \theta = m \lambda$ gives the **minimum** (m=1 is first minimum and so on) and that I can approximate $\sin \theta \approx \theta$ but other than that I am quite stuck. How can I proceed from here and approximate the angle $\theta$?

*I have seen the other [thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/330231/271720) related to this topic but I did not understand the answer there.*

Comment: Here is a good explanation from a textbook: https://openstax.org/books/college-physics/pages/27-5-single-slit-diffraction

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formula for secondary maxima in Fraunhofer Diffraction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/531698/)